# Prevent user from keying date into HTML5 date field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

I have an HTML5 'date' input field on a form. The dates it displayes are limited to a given range.
This works fine.

I need to prevent users from being able to key a date into this field using a keyboard, making them rely on the calendar dropdown provided by the field and using the mouse to click on a chosen date.

How can this be done? Does the 'date' input have any control like this?

Many thanks in advance. :)

Comment: One simple solution (if I understood your issue) is to set the input to `readonly`, something like `<input type="date" readonly />` But of course HTML can be changed very easily

Comment: BUT... you should anyway validate your date server-side if that's important for you. Any validation/restriction happening on the client is user-friendlyness and sparing a roundtrip to the server, but the real data validation is only possible on the server.

Comment: Although this is possible, from an accessibility standpoint I would advice against doing it: some of your users may not be able to use a mouse in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Can't understand why I've got a -2 on this question though... what have I done wrong? :)

Comment: @dradd, I did not downvote, but they're most probably due to the two usual suspects: no apparent research effort in your question and no code to show what you tried to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Frederic... I'll learn for next time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

Javascript/Jquery:

```
$("input").keydown(false);
```

HTML:

```
<input type="Date" />
```

See the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7n4G4/147/).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by stopping the default work of keyup event.

```
//HTML
<input id="date" type=date>

//Javascript
document.getElementById("date").onkeyup=function(){
   return false;
}
```

Working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/y5Fpn/